# JQuery Mobile Fixed Toolbar Hide

Tags: jquery-mobile, show-hide, fixed, jquery-mobile-toolbars

I was trying to simulate "tap to show/hide the fixed toolbar" when I found out that it's already the default function hahaha!

By default works charmly: it starts "show" and when it taps then "hide" and when taps again "shows" etc. PERFECT!

The problem is that I want it to **start hidden** and when the user taps shows and so on...

I used

```
$(".divBotoneraSimple").hide();
```

but then it doesn't show when tapped! I also tried:

```
$.mobile.fixedToolbars.hide(true);
$("[data-position='fixed']").fixedtoolbar('hide');
```

but both of them "stop my App" when triggered!

In order words I need to trigger those hides from javascript and still respond to tapping!

Answer (score 1):

Use `.toolbar()` method with `show`, `hide` or `toggle`.

```
$(".ui-header, .ui-footer").toolbar("toggle");
```

Note that if you are at the top of the page, the header won't be hidden, only the footer, and vice versa.